# Howto deactivate caching inside a jsp page

Tags: http, jsp, jstl, cache-control, no-cache

I understand there is a HTTP response header directive to disable page caching:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
```

I can modify the header by "hand":

```
 <%response.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");%>
```

But is there a "nice" way to make the JSP interpreter return this header line in the server response?

(I checked the <%@page ...%> directive. It seems there is nothing like that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also add

```
response.addHeader("Expires","-1");
response.addHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```

to your headers and give that a shot.

Comment: I tried with the following code, its is not caching the page but when I hit browser back button, browser says this document no more exist , reload the page. Why it is not reloading the page automatically ? `<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
 %>`

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a servlet, then I believe what you posted in the question would be the correct approach.  I'm not aware of any way to do this in the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0"> 
 <jsp:scriptlet><![CDATA[
   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
 ]]></jsp:scriptlet>
</jsp:root>
```

You must put the response header inside `<jsp:root />`. Also, I would instead recommend it sending this from your servlet instead of JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC some browsers may ignore the cache control settings in some contexts.  The 'safe' workaround for this was to always get a page (even an AJAX chunk) with a new query string variable (like the time.)