# Any update to tomcat pages isn't reflected when accessing via browser

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Howto deactivate caching inside a jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161937/howto-deactivate-caching-inside-a-jsp-page)

I started to learn servlets today and came to a strange problem. No matter what change I make on the files, that change isn't reflected when I access the page on firefox. I even deleted the page in question, but I can still see it.

I tried restarting tomcat, but that was of no use. What's also strange is that I can't visit `localhost:8080` on any other browser.

Any further information, all you have to do is ask.

---

#### EDIT:

After restarting my computer, the changes began to be answered. Then I wrote a servlet, compiled it and mapped it. But when I try to load it, it just goes to an infinite loop. Then it makes impossible for me to access any page on the server.

Comment: It's not a cache issue. I cleared up the cache on Firefox and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the answer was this. I remove everything I had related to tomcat7 and reinstalled it. That made everything work. I think I might have installation conflicts regarding the different tomcat's I had.

Thanks everyone for the help.