# Spring Security - No way to avoid cache-control

Tags: spring, caching, spring-security

I have an application and use a controller mapping of spring to load images to my users. (InputStream, response, etc).

In my controller I set headers to cache-control, baseaded on files, etc. But there's always pragma: no-cache and Cache-Control:"max-age=0" inside all requests, and that's replace my response settings.

I was trying everything to solve this, but nothing works.

I already read all page and try everything I found about that:
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html

My spring security.xml has:

```
    <security:headers disabled="true"/>
```

Anyone have a good idea to solve this?

Remember that to load the images I need to load through my controller, I never call static directly.

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to set the headers in your controller? Does the problem still happen if you remove Spring Security entirely?

Answer (score 19):

The `Cache-Control` headers can be controlled on a per action basis by overriding them in the `HttpServletResponse`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String someAction(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform, public, max-age=86400");

    // ...
}
```

No need to fiddle with the Spring Security configuration.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-cache-control.

Comment: This is the ONLY approach I found to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution has saved a lot of time.

Comment: This will duplicate the header instead of overriding it. I am getting `no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, max-age=7200`

Comment: @Kumait Works with Spring 5.1.9

Answer (score 12):

In case one uses Java based configuration, cache control headers can be disabled this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
class SpringWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }
}
```

This will remove CacheControlHeadersWriter and Spring won't write cache control headers any more.

Comment: Where do I put this config?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works for me.

Comment: Disabling default Spring security behavior is bad idea. You read more here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cache-control-headers

Answer (score 0):

Per [Spring Security reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html) (3.2.0) you've linked to,

> All of the default headers can be easily added using the  element with no child elements

Simply adding `headers` by itself will turn on all child elements (e.g. cache control, xxs, ...). Either don't include headers at all or explicitly specify which child elements you want to enable.

BTW, I don't think `disabled` is an attribute of headers (for 3.2.0). If you're using [version 4.0](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/headers.html), there is a `disabled` attribute as well as `disabled-defaults`, which might be the one you want.

Comment: Tryed now and not solve.
I want to remove the "no-cache" of my requests, no include them.

Comment: What did you try? Can you show what your updated config looks like.

Comment: Sure,

The config now is:
<security:http use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >
  
   
  <security:headers />
  <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
   

    </security:http>

Comment: For security version < 4.0, <security:headers /> will turn on all default headers (including cache control). If you don't need any headers, just remove the <security:headers/>. If you need some headers, then explicitly list them. If your security version is 4.0, then try adding the attribute `disabled-defaults="true"`

Comment: I tried too, get out everything and it's the same.
I don't need anything about that, but it keep no-cache in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [aha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36459244/746236)'s answer. You also need to override the Pragma header with some garbage.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String someAction(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform, public, max-age=86400");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "");
    // ...
}
```

The Expires header also still shows in the response, but seems to be overridden by the Cache-Control header in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work for you in spring 5.X

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers()
        .defaultsDisabled()
        .cacheControl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It has been sometime - but while researching on the same problem, I found this post and this worked or me -

[disable caching for specific url in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530575/disable-caching-for-specific-url-in-spring-security/30949227#30949227)

The beauty of the solution referred above is that it enables each header specifically using its original class, and uses antmatchers to align specific request paths to the respective header. In my case, I used a separate Cache reference for my static resources with cache expiry set and another one for all jsps with no cache. Since it is an ant matcher, the controller uri can be matched using the same approach.