# Spring controller doesn't get Cache Control header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I wanto set max age in cache control header in respon. I have write this as below, but still has max-age 0. i want to set max age only for one method, so i wantnot to disable default. i thik is should ovveride.

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "get value by foreign currency", response = Property.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/properties/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<BigDecimal> getValueByForeignCurrency(@PathVariable Long id,
                                                @RequestParam("currency") String currency, Locale locale) {
    if (!ForeignCurrency.isLegalCurrency(currency)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Currency: " + currency + " is not legal");
    }

    BigDecimal foreignValue = propertyService.getPropertyValueInForeignCurrency(id, currency, locale);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS))
            .body(foreignValue);
}
```

Sombody know what i done wrong ?

Comment: `SpringSecurity`, by default sets to `no-cache` mode. You can set cache settings in `HttpServletResponse` object. 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String welcome(HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform, public, max-age=3600");
  return "welcome";
 }`

Comment: Thank you vaery much. I changed it to :
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform, public, max-age=3600");

        count += 1;

        return "Ale ma kota a kot ma ale a count" + String.valueOf(count);
    } and in response is Cache-Control →no-transform, public, max-age=3600 but I think it does'nt works. After reloaded count is increase.

Comment: okay. How are you validating the response cache headers? By having counter in a method and increment it? Ideally, you should check the browser network console and check the response headers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome is the link

Comment: My response headers are :My Cache-Control:no-transform, public, max-age=3600
Content-Length:34
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 30 May 2017 10:51:24 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

Comment: and general:  Status Code:200  deosn't has additional info that it is load from disc

Comment: If you see 3600 in the response headers, then your code is working. What exactly you want to achieve by adding the cache headers? You want browsers/clients to cache the content?

Comment: I want to browser not invoke another request to server after max age. Because currency value change only one as day.

Comment: So do you have aby idea ?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412918/spring-security-no-way-to-avoid-cache-control and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164014/how-to-enable-http-response-caching-in-spring-boot

Comment: We have set the cache headers, just disable `Pragma:no-cache` and it should work

Comment: harshavmb - thank you very much for help

Comment: Glad to now that it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

`SpringSecurity` by default sets to `no-cache` mode.

You can set cache settings in `HttpServletResponse` object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String welcome(HttpServletResponse response) { 
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform, public, max-age=3600"); 
    return "welcome"; 
}
```

Refer [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-cache-control) for official documentation.

Comment: There is also Prgama - no-cache header, and it is default set too. If I  disable  cache in security config it will works, but i want to only for one controllers method.  This is the problem now. Btw thank you very much for answer

Comment: okay `Pragma:no-cache` is being used for backward compatibility with HTTP 1.0 version.  `Cache-Control` is used for HTTP1.1, `Pragma` header works in the absence of `Cache-Control` header. Yours is a bit tricky case as both are conflicting.

Comment: Well, can you try adding this `response.setHeader("Pragma", "cache");` to your controller and try