# Setting custom cache-control header from configuration XML for Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am attempting to configure `cache-control` response header to a custom value via my Spring Security configuration XML.  Unfortunately, it seems like I'm only able to *disable* the `cache-control` header from the XML configuration [as per the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-cache-control):

```
<http>
    <headers defaults-disable="true">
        <cache-control />
    </headers>
</http>
```

Being this seems to be the case, I attempted to create a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as so:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("******* SETTING CUSTOM CACHE-CONTROL....");
        StaticHeadersWriter writer = new StaticHeadersWriter("Cache-Control", "2592000");
        RequestMatcher resourcesMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*");
        HeaderWriter resourcesHeaderWriter = new DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter(resourcesMatcher, writer);
        http.headers().cacheControl().disable().addHeaderWriter(resourcesHeaderWriter);
        http.headers().disable();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, even though the class is in fact initially called, it seems like the configuration is actually overwritten by the XML, as the `cache-control` response header still appears to be set to the defaults:

[image: Response headers still show cache-control defaults for Spring Security]

Any thoughts on how I can specify something similar with the XML file itself, preferably able to match a specific pattern (ex. *.js)?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me try that--let me ask, though, is there a way to selectively apply headers?  My main goal was to only modify the default cache-control for JS files.

Comment: You mean for some ANT pattern? Yes, you can do that at least in Java configuration. With XML it is more complicated but possible.

Comment: Yes, ANT pattern...as for the `header` XML element, I am still seeing no way to configure this under `headers` ?  The only attribute listed is disabled: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-cache-control

Comment: Can you provide a link?  The cache-control link I posted up there is literally listed as a child element of the headers tag as shown here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-headers-children -- am I missing something?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-header

Comment: Thanks @dur--that seemed to work!  Any way to selectively apply the header?

Comment: What about using a filter ? After changing the code press **CTRL** and **R** button to see the changes.

Comment: @slashp: You can create a `DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter` and reference it in your `header` tag.

Comment: @dur--can you please post as the answer and I will mark it?  Thank you!!

Comment: I believe the answer that you want is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530575/disable-caching-for-specific-url-in-spring-security/30949227#30949227

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer that you want is already described in the question here:

[disable caching for specific url in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530575/disable-caching-for-specific-url-in-spring-security/30949227#30949227)

By doing something like this:

```
<security:http>
[intercept-url, etc omitted...]
        <security:headers>
            <!-- selectively applied to dynamic pages only via pattern matching,  -->
            <security:header ref="noCacheHeaders"/>
        </security:headers>
    </security:http>    

<bean id="noCacheHeaders" class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
                <constructor-arg value="/index.html"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.CacheControlHeadersWriter"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```